# A condition for birational equivalence to projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $f,g\in\mathbb{C}[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ be coprime homogeneous polynomials of degrees $d$ and $d-1$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Show that $V(f-x_{0}g)$ is a rational variety over $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. birationally equivalent to $\mathbb{P}^{n}_{\mathbb{C}}$.

I have no idea even where to start. Can somebody please give me a detailed explanation?

Comment: To construct a birational equivalence, it is enough to construct an isomorphism between the “meromorphic function fields”.

Comment: @Mindlack: Of course. But I have no idea how to do this. Can somebody please show me a solution, and explain it to me step-by-step?

Comment: Which variables are $f$ and $g$ involving? How many of them? Do they involve $x_0$? Are they homogeneous? Which coprime condition are you talking about: do they have no common zero, or do they have no common irreducible factor?

Comment: I have tried to, but failed. It doesn't seem that examples are bringing me any further. I am completely at a loss.

Comment: This is false in general; for instance if $f=x_1^2$ and $g=x_0$.  Are you sure you have stated the problem correctly?

Comment: @EricWofsey I corrected it now. $f$ and $g$ are supposed to be in $\mathbb{C}[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$.

Comment: Think about what the coordinate ring of $V(f-x_0g)$ looks like, and in particular what the relation $f-x_0g$ says about $x_0$.

Comment: @EricWofsey All I can see is that $x_{0}=\frac{f}{g}$ on $V$. How does that bring me further?

Comment: Well then what would the fraction field of the coordinate ring be?

Comment: Aaaaargh I see it now! The coordinate ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$

Comment: That was a classical case of not seeing the wood for all the trees.

Comment: This is also worth thinking about geometrically I think. Consider the copy of $\mathbb C^n$ that you get as $V(x_0)$. If you restrict the projection map from $\mathbb C^{n+1}$ to $V(f - x_0g)$, what does the general fiber look like?